# Compatibility of Build From Source Tensorflow Versions with CUDA Version

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

I have seen the list of **tested** TF version and it's CUDA version compatibility [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations), but I am having a doubt whether every TF version can be **build from source** with any CUDA version or not. For example:- can TF 1.14 build with CUDA 11.1 or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, T.F. 1x is not compatible with CUDA 11.1. For CUDA 11.1 you need to go for T.F. 2.3 or higher.

If you wish to use T.F. 1.x then the best will be to use CUDA 10.0-10.2